# How is the nuclear norm convex whereas the weighted nuclear norm is not?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, non-convex-optimization, nuclear-norm

In [Weighted Nuclear Norm Minimization with Application to Image Denoising](http://nuit-blanche.blogspot.com/2014/05/wnnm-weighted-nuclear-norm-minimization.html), it is stated that nuclear norm of a matrix $\mathbf{X}$, given by

$$\|\mathbf{X}\|_{*}=\sum_{i} \sigma_{i}(\mathbf{X})$$

where $\sigma_{i}(\mathbf{X})$ are the singular values, is *convex*. In the same paper, the weighted nuclear norm, given by

$$\|\mathbf{X}\|_{*,\mathbf{W}}=\sum_{i} w_{(i,i)}\sigma_{i}(\mathbf{X})$$

is *non-convex*. I am unable to prove this argument with Jensen's inequality. Kindly, help.

Comment: I actually believe it *is* convex if the weights are nonincreasing. That is, $w_i\geq w_j$ whenever $\sigma_i\geq\sigma_j$.

Comment: A simple case: let $w_n=1$ for $n>1$ and all other weights are zero. That is certainly nonconvex.

Comment: The singular values are *ordered* by definition.  That's the key...

Comment: Right. So consider a 2x2 case, with 2 diagonal matrices. Let the largest singular value be in the (1,1) position for one, and the (2,2) position for the other. Shouldn't be difficult to find a counterexample by choosing the values and weights judiciously.

Comment: And in case it is not clear: you don't "prove nonconvexity" per se; rather you *disprove* convexity. And you typically do *that* with a single counterexample: two points that violate the secant inequality at at least one point along the segment.