# Problem in defining weighted nuclear norm in CVX

Tags: convex-optimization, normed-spaces, matlab, cvx, nuclear-norm

I want to define a **weighted nuclear norm**, i.e.,

$$\|X\|_{w,*}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}{w_i\sigma_i(X)}$$

in CVX, but I can't. CVX has a function for nuclear norm called `norm_nuc`, but I do not know how to change it to work with my function. The problem is that CVX does not understand `svd`.

Does anyone have experience in CVX ?

Comment: Looks like the [weighted nuclear norm may not be convex](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1081446/339790).